# including current date in printfile names

Tags: date, printing, include, filenames, kantu

I am using a macro to obtain data from a website and save to a print file using the print function on the specific website page.
In the print window i can select "print to pdf" but do not know how to format the output filename to reflect the current date.
The macro will be run every month to save a snapshot of the website's data.
I have tried several suggestions from the forums but haven't found a solution that works.
Filename required is of the form "yyyymmdd_account_summary.pdf"
Using Kantu as the macro recorder in firefox 68 on fedora 29.

i tried setting the print file name to 
$(date +"%y%m%d")_account_summary.pdf
but this only created a file named
$(date +"%y%m%d")_account_summary.pdf
no variables were substituted.
obviously i am doing something simple wrong but cannot see it.

Expected resulting filename
20190731_account_summary.pdf
actual name that is created
$(date +"%y%m%d")_account_summary.pdf which is clearly wrong

Comment: Please add a tag to your post, that tells us what language you are using. Is this bash scripting?

Comment: not bash scripting. just trying to have the printfile name include the current date when printing to .pdf from the standard print menu as invoked from the firefox File|print menu.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I did not see kantu, or did not notice it as the macro recorder. You should always add major used tools into the tags

Answer (score 0):

We are not very familiar with Kantu but I suggest we do it in three steps.

Step 1. Let your macro runs periodically to a fixed file name (/tmp/my_temp_file.pdf).

Step 2. Write a script (bash or python) to monitor the file modify/overwrite timestamp and whenever it detects changes, copy the file (/tmp/my_temp_file.pdf) into "yyyymmdd_account_summary.pdf"

Step 3. Make a cronjob that invoke the script periodically.

Comment: can you give details of exactly how to include the datestamp in the filename? Form required is yyyymmddfilename.pdf

Comment: Kantu is just a macro recorder. it is just used to record mouseclicks as i navigate through the website so i can setup to play them back each month to save data from the website.